# How to give user root permissions?

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, root, privileges

I just installed Arch. Works great. I created a new user, logged in with it and now I'm trying to install several things with `pacman`. But I keep getting the error: `error: you cannot perform this operation unless you are root.` I can use `pacman` with root just fine, but is there a way to allow my new user to perform these actions?

I tried logging into root and using gpasswd:

`gpasswd -a jack root`

but that didn't do anything.

Comment: As a general note, the Arch Linux wiki is really useful and detailed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should read the Arch Wiki page on [sudo](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo).

> sudo ("substitute user do") allows a system administrator to delegate authority to give certain users (or groups of users) the ability to run some (or all) commands as root or another user while providing an audit trail of the commands and their arguments.

You can install `sudo` from the repositories and then configure it to allow your user, `jack`, access to privileged commands by editing `/etc/sudoers`. Make sure you do this using the `visudo` command.

To give the user `jack` full root privileges, you would add this line:

```
jack ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 10):

What I usually do is enable root privileges for a specific group. That way you can just add users you want root privileges to that group.

Edit `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo` and add (or comment out):

```
%wheel      ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Then add your user to that group:

```
gpasswd -a jack wheel
```

Comment: Even though the answer that is marked as accepted and it will work, I believe this answer is a better due to using groups over modifying sudoers.

Answer (score 0):

> I can use pacman with root just fine, but it there a way to allow my new user to perform these actions?

You could create your `$USER`, adding them to the `wheel` group alone:

```
useradd -Ng wheel --create-home --no-log-init $USER
```

Then update `/etc/sudoers` [as suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47364/111911) by Eric Lennartsson. But if you're looking for a programmatic approach you can instead create a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` like:

```
echo "$USER ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/dont-prompt-$USER-for-password
```

The method above [was suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/1162819/401660) by Boris in Ask Ubuntu and it doesn't require use of `visudo` at all. When using it with pacman prefix the commands with sudo like:

```
sudo pacman -S docker docker-compose
```